# What's the name for this writing of a polynomial of degree 2?

Tags: terminology

Going from $$2 x^2 + 12 x + 25$$

to the form *(1)* $$2(x+3)^2+7$$

is called *"mise sous forme canonique du polynôme du second degré"* in French, but it seems (I looked in various sources) that the translation for that is **not** *"canonical form*".

**Does this way of writing a polynomial of degree 2 have a name in English?**

---

Note : (1) is very useful when, for example, you want to compute the primitive of:
$$\frac{1}{2 x^2 + 12 x + 25}$$
When writing $$\frac{1}{2(x+3)^2+7},$$
you are not for from $k \ u' / (1 + u^2)$ whose primitive is $k\ arctan(u)+C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called *completing the square*.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square

Comment: That is it, yes! You're welcome.